# What's the common verb to describe a rainbow?

Tags: word-usage, verb-usage

For whatever reason, I had in mind that the common verb used to describe a rainbow's "state" is *bent*, as in *"a rainbow bent over the landscape"*.

However, I just Googled *"rainbow bent over"*, and there are really a small amount of results. Googling *"rainbow * over"* didn't help me understand what's the common verb, as well.

What's the common verb to describe a rainbow? perhaps it's *"arch*? maybe *"stretch"*? something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a 'common' verb in use for that purpose. 'Bent' is certainly an accurate description and gets the idea across. However, there are some reasons you might not use 'bent'. There is a subtle connotation to the word 'bent' that suggests the thing you're talking about was once straight and might be straight again. It's a term more suited to a solid object than the shape of something as big, beautiful and ephemeral as a rainbow.

The term that comes to mind for me is 'arched'. That word has a more structural, graceful and poetic connotation and better describes the majestic, inspiring sight of a rainbow in the sky. I think most people would think of using 'arched' before they thought of 'bent' or any other description.

Comment: In France a rainbow is an 'arc en ciel'.

Answer (score 2):

*Arch* sounds best to me, though there’s nothing unidiomatic about *bend*. Both are used in this [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/weather/2019/10/23/stunning-rainbow-enchants-washington-heralds-nationals-world-series-win/) article in captions:

> Rainbow arched across the sky in Gainesville, Va., on Tuesday evening, with a Washington Nationals hat in the foreground.

> A rainbow bends over the Capitol on Tuesday evening.

Comment: To indicate simply *existence* one could say "a rainbow appears" or "is visible."